# Numpy, given norm returns possible cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

Is there some simple tool in numpy which given a value x returns three random coordinates whose modulus is x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think you'll find something in numpy for the purpose, but this will be pretty fast:

```
from numpy.random import normal
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import allclose
def random_vec(modulus):
    while True:
        y = normal(size=(3,))
        if not allclose(y,0):
            y *= modulus / norm(y)
            return y
```

Above I am assuming that with module of a vector you mean an [L2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html) norm. Notice that we must check that at least one coordinate is not too close to zero (or zero!), so that we do not have numerical rounding problems when we rescale the components.

EDIT: using now `normal()` instead of `rand()`

The reason why we pick the coordinates from a normal distribution (and then of course rescale them) in order to obtain a random point on the sphere of radius `modulus` is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points). Read also unutbu's comments below.

Comment: If you use `np.random.normal(size=(3,1))` instead of `np.random.rand(3)`, then the points generated will be [uniformly distributed on the sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points).

Comment: If you use `rand(3)` then you are selecting a point on a unit cube and then projecting that onto a sphere. That gives more points near the sides and fewer near the corners.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want the 3-dimensional Cartesian coordinates `(X,Y,Z)`, you can do this with two random choices of angle in spherical polar coordinates and then converting back to Cartesian:

```
import numpy as np

# Example data: three values of x = sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)
x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])

n = len(x)
theta = np.arccos(2 * np.random.random(n) - 1)
phi = np.random.random(n) * 2. * np.pi

X = x * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
Y = x * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
Z = x * np.cos(theta)
```

gives (for example):

```
[-2.60520852  0.01145881  1.01482376]
[-0.85300437  0.29508229 -1.54315779]
[ 1.21871742 -0.95540313  3.54806944]
```

Comment: a remark: doing it like this you have that `phi` is truly random, and `cos(phi)` and `sin(phi)` are functions of a random variable, so that the coordinates are not technically as random as `phi`.